# My wordpress shows apache2 ubuntu default web page "it works" in remote hosting

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, hosting

recently i upload my local wordpress web site to a remote hosting, i used gFTP, but my principal wordpress page always shows me the apache2 ubuntu default web page "it works" in the remote hosting./wordpress/
If a type in the web browser http://mywebsite.com/wordpress/ appears a link part of my website (not home)
At this point i dont know what to do, maybe change .htaccess in my wordpress remote hosting, anyhelp is appreciated, thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

You are receiving Apache web server default page. Make sure you have set default page in .htaccess file.

Locate .htaccess file from cPanel and open it in editor.

Paste the following code at the top of the page to configure your desired index page. In following example below, first.html is set as default page.

```
#Alternate default index page
DirectoryIndex first.html
```

You can also list more than one file in the configuration. The file will be read left to right and check for them in that order. In following example,  index.htm, index.html, and index.php are added to the list. First the server will check for first.html, if it does not find a file with that name, it continues to index.htm and so on.

```
#Alternate default index pages
DirectoryIndex first.html index.htm index.html index.php
```

Be sure to hit the Save Changes button in the upper right corner to save your new .htaccess configuration.

Comment: Worked for me by setting DirectoryIndex index.php in .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your database then in wp-option table, change the home url to you current domain name.